# Convert z-score scaled matrix to normalized matrix

Tags: r, seurat, z-score

I'm quite new in scRNAseq analysis. From a public database I downloaded a z-score scaled matrix that I will utilize form my analysis. The function FindAllMarker() from Seurat package utilize normalized data, that are not available.

Is it possible convert z-score scaled matrix to normalized matrix?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate in the [bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/), you would get better answers there (as it's not really an R question).